# Link does not work in HTML. I have used "<a href="fileName"></a>" Tag

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

My link doesn't work in HTML and I don't know why.

```html
<div class="banner-text">
    <ul>
                <li><h3><a href="chawla.html">HOME</a></h3></li>
                </li><h3><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></h3></li>
                </li><h3><a href="cont.html">CONTACT</a></h3></li>
                </li><h3><a href="stud.html">STUDENT's CORNER</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
    <h1 class="big">CHAWLA CLASSES</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Why do you nest your markup that way, and not the `a` tag in the `h3`?

Comment: When I Hover over it behaves like normal text

Comment: And what should happen instead? You haven't provided any information about hovering states

Comment: Do you want a hover effect or the functionality of anchor tags?

Comment: It Does not Work

Comment: Put the `<a>` tags **inside** the `<li>` tags.

Comment: when I hover cursor should become a pointer

Comment: Share your problem stackblitz

Comment: please add more details such as, what is the expected behaviour and what all have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [validator](https://validator.nu/).

Only `<li>` elements may be children of `<ul>` elements.

Put the links in the list items, not the other way around.

---

Asides:

- Level 3 heading elements should be used for **headings**. If the entirely content of a list item is a heading, you are using the wrong markup. Apply CSS if you want to format the list items.
- Screen readers will tend to spell out words written in ALL CAPS letter-by-letter. If you want something to be *visually* rendered in capital letters: Use the CSS `text-transform` property.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it like this

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="chawla.html">Home</a> </li>
   <li> <a href="about.html">About Us</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="cont.html">Contact</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="stud.html">Student's Corner</a> </li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE: Well, I check again but it works. There is the screenshots

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXjKf.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2aFw.png)

Comment: when I click on it doesn't go to another page

Comment: You should check your html code again. Because It will work

Answer (score 0):

Put the anchor tag inside the `<li>` tag. If it doesn't work, go-to developer console to trace it .

Comment: What is developer Console

Comment: Do you mean Inspect

Comment: The browser inspection